# Вызов консольного приложения по очистке метаданных exiftool из window-службы

Tags: c#, cmd, metadata

Добрый день всем.
Нужен одновременно совет по проектированию приложения и конкретная помощь.
Стоит задача - очищать метаданные перед отправкой для различных типов файлов. Офисные документы, фотографии, pdf и т.п.
 
Суть приложения такая - поднимается windows-служба, которая мониторит появление файлов в папке, обрабатывает поступления и переносит файл уже без метаданных в результирующую папку. Удалять требуется вcе вообще, что можно удалить и/или заменить на пустые значения. 
Самописный вариант извлечения и удаления exif/xmp-метаданных спотыкается на огромном их количестве, поэтому мне сейчас выдали exiftool (https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) и сказали работать от него.
Это консольное приложение, написанное на Perl. Для него существуют врапперы в .Net (ProcessStartInfo + Process), но тут свои проблемы.

Вопрос 1 - нормально ли создавать консольное приложение на каждый новый файл (их может быть неограниченное количество закинуто в папку мониторинга), или есть какие-то базовые правила, которые лучше учитывать. Насколько вообще допустим вызов консоли из службы и нет ли тут подводных камней?

Вопрос 2 - ручной запуск приложения из консоли windows использует кодировку консоли, поэтому exiftool.exe отлично распознает файлы с русскими буквами в названии. Как при оборачивании консольного вызова сохранить это поведение? Заявленная в документации опция -charset filename=CHARSET не помогла.

Вопрос 3 - если есть альтернативы exiftool, позволяющие не только вычитывать метаданные, но и менять их - буду рада любому направлению.

Comment: exiftool умеет и менять их. А зачем поднимать именно службу ? Мониторишь нужную папку, при появлении файла создаешь отдельный поток, в котором работаешь с файлом(удаляешь метаданные и переносишь) и усе

Comment: @Lolidze потому что вспоминать о том, что надо перезапустить приложение, которое что-то там мониторит никто из админов не будет.
Но это полбеды в общем-то.
Все еще не понимаю, как работать с русскими буквами в названии файла. 

Есть опыт работы именно с exiftool? При разборе враппера я вижу. что приложение возвращает всегда {ready} и ни слова о том, обработался файл или нет и почему. Т.е. на картинку с именем на русском вернется именно ready и все. Понятно, что это не ожидаемый ответ, но хотелось бы подробностей от приложения.

Comment: Ну можно же просто настроить аудит для папки и натравить системный планировщик на события аудита. В планировщик закинуть батник для ExifTool, или просто команду запуска, если одной команды достаточно, и ни каких проблем с кодировкой быть не должно по идее. Лучше конечно батник, для обработки нескольких файлов в цикле, аудит (как и FileSystemWatcher) пропускает иногда события

Comment: @rdorn а можно чуть подробнее?
сейчас у меня есть сетевая папка, с сильно разветвленной системой подпапок (до 5 тыщ элементов на 1 уровне, в каждой папке рандомное кол-во документов и уровень вложенности). Сейчас у меня висит служба, которая мониторит событие копирования файла в эту структуру, запускает в отдельном потоке обработку и кладет результат в итоговую папку, которая создается на том же уровне, что и файл, если не была создана ранее. Все ошибки кладутся в события винды, а оттуда рассылаются по адресатам отдельной прогой.

Как это можно сделать планировщиком? Где почитать?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx  
https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn319068(v=ws.11).aspx   

Насколько часто у вас добавляются файлы в вашу структуру? Системный аудит может съесть много пространства на свой журнал, надо внимательно посмотреть настройки журнала, и папку, на которую он нацелен, чем точнее, тем лучше.

Comment: Но возможно, оно вам и не подойдет, вы же только в комментарии указали что есть дополнительные задачи. Если в консоли можно написать скрипт для выполнения этих задач, то этот скрипт можно прикрутить к планировщику, если возможностей командной строки не достаточно для решения, можно попробовать PowerShell (поддерживает C#), JScript или VBScript, смотря что вам ближе. Задача в общем-то админская, и ее можно решить почти без программирования (минимальный скриптинг при наличии необходимых консольных инструментов), решать вам.